# Writing a Python function to calculate Pi

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pi

newbie here:

Just learning Python and this one has me pooped. It's coming up with a function for manually computing Pi, the [Madhava way.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama#The_value_of_.CF.80_.28pi.29) - Also known as exercise #16 from here: http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/thinkcspy/Functions/thinkcspyExercises.html

Can somebody take a look at my discombobulated and overly complex code and tell me if I'm missing something? Much thanks. (look at the equation on the wiki page first, otherwise my code will make no sense - well, it still may not.)

```
 import math

 def denom_exp(iters):
    for i in range(0, iters):
      exp = 3^iters
      return exp

 def base_denom(iters):
    for i in range(0, iters):
      denom = 1 + 2*iters
      return denom

 def myPi(iters):
    sign = 1
    pi = 0
    for i in range(0, iters):
       pi = pi + sign*(1/((base_denom(iters))*denom_exp(iters)))
       sign = -1 * sign
    pi = (math.sqrt(12))*pi
    return pi

 thisisit = myPi(10000)
 print(thisisit)
```

Comment: I think you want to use `i` inside your for loops, not `iters`

Comment: which loop in particular?

Comment: sure? I replaced all the iters in the for loops with i, and getting TypeErrors of unsupported operand types.

Comment: i think replacing iters with i is right but PyCharm is freaking out about the pi=pi+sign*(1 etcetc line when I replace the iters with i's....

Comment: That's not the only problem. Where appropriate you will need to cast integers to float. Google python division maybe.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, manually computing Pi, the [Madhava](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhava_of_Sangamagrama#The_value_of_.CF.80_.28pi.29) way.

```
import math

def myPi(iters):
  sign = 1
  x = 1
  y = 0
  series = 0 
  for i in range (iters):
    series = series + (sign/(x * 3**y))
    x = x + 2
    y = y + 1
    sign = sign * -1
  myPi = math.sqrt(12) * series

  return myPi

print(myPi(1000))
```

Comment: i feel like this code makes a lot of sense and really helped simplify my overly scattalogical code - but i'm still getting a "Process finished with an error code 0". Any clue why?