# Python: estimate Pi with trig functions as efficiently as possible

Tags: python, python-3.x, trigonometry

I have an assignment where I need to approximate Pi in a computationally efficient manner. Here is my strategy: I use a unit circle, the angle bisector of an isoceles triangle, and the definition of sin. I drew a diagram:

[image]

For example, if I want to use an hexagon (6 points/6 sides), I simply need to compute `a`:(`0.5*sin(2*pi/2*x`) and multiply it by (`2*x`). Finally, since `Pi = Circumference/Diameter`, then my approximation of Pi = polygon perimeter (since `Diameter = 1`).

Essentially:

```
from math import sin, pi
def computePi(x):    #x: number of points desired
    p = x*sin(pi/x)
    print(p)

computePi(10000)
3.141592601912665
```

It works, and I think it's as efficient as it gets, no? Thank you for your time!

EDIT: to avoid circularity, I redid it using Archimedes algorithm using only the Pythagorean theroem:

[image]

Code:

```
from math import sqrt

def approxPi(x):                  #x: number of times you want to recursively apply Archmidedes' algorithm
    s = 1                         #Unit circle
    a = None; b = None;   
    for i in range(x):
        a = sqrt(1 - (s/2)**2)
        b = 1 - a
        print('The approximate value of Pi using a {:5g}-sided polygon is {:1.8f}'.format(6*2**(i),(s*6*2**(i))/2))
        s = sqrt(b**2 + (s/2)**2)
```

Comment: so, you calculate `pi` using the value of `pi`? hmm

Comment: If you are importing pi, why not just use it?

Comment: Actually, this is a good homework question (although perhaps off-topic on Stack Overflow since it is working code). The circularity can be hidden by using `math.sin(math.radians(y))` where `y` is the appropriate angle in degrees. Since this is an historically accurate way to approximate `pi`, it is possible to e.g. divide 360 by powers of 2 so that the needed sines can be computed from first-principles using the half-angle formula in a way that no prior knowledge of `pi` is needed.

Comment: @UrielEli Actually, I could use degrees instead of radians: sin(pi/x) = sin(180/x), no? Trig functions are simply functions that represent ratios in a right-angle triangle, no?

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you! Using radians does introduce circularity, but degrees don't

Comment: @Johnathan `math.sin` is computed by an algorithm which assumes that the input is in radians, and converting from degrees to radians requires `pi`. That hides the circularity but doesn't eliminate it. If you have some independent method of computing `sin(x degrees)` then it wouldn't be circular.

Comment: @JohnColeman I could a Maclaurin series to compute sin(30). That should do it! :)

Comment: Gauss–Legendre algorithm looks fairly simple, and is supposed to be be faster then trig.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better is

```
print(4 * math.atan(1))
```

This does not use pi in any obvious way in the calculation (though as @Jean-FrançoisFabre comments, pi is probably used in the function definition), and in addition to the trig function it has just one simple multiplication. Of course, there is also

```
print(2 * math.acos(0))
```

and

```
print(2 * math.asin(1))
```

Comment: It probably uses pi, but at least it uses the one defined internally in the trigonometric functions.

Comment: OR just use `print(pi)`. No calculation required

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: But that does not use a "trig function" as the question's title states.

Comment: @RoryDaulton `print(sin and pi)` then :-P

Comment: is `math.pi` computed using `math.atan` or is `math.atan` using a fixed value of `pi` ? chicken-and-egg situation. But this answers answers the question exactly. Maybe the question is not that good. Computing pi should be done without trig functions, ex like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29190407/writing-a-python-function-to-calculate-pi

Comment: `math.pi` probably just uses the value of pi stored in the CPU, which I know is stored in the x86 CPU. The arctangent function can be (approximately) calculated through a very nice Maclaurin series, combined with range reduction. But my favorite way to calculate pi is the Machin formula combined with two arctangent calculations. There is no necessary circularity here.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Do you have a link for pi being stored in the CPU? I couldn't find it.

Comment: I got that info from page 3-210 in a downloaded copy of [this Intel manual](https://www.scribd.com/document/5510435/Intel-R-Architecture-Software-Developer-s-Manual-Volume-2-Instruction-Set-Reference-Manual) or page 7-39 in Volume 1 of that manual. Also look for FLDPI in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Original_8087_instructions).

Answer (score 2):

A fun albeit not very efficient solution is to use Euler's solution of the [Basel Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem):

```
from math import sqrt

def psum(n):
    return sum(1/k**2 for k in range(1,n+1))

def approxPi(n):
    s = psum(n)
    return sqrt(6*s)
```

For example,

```
>>> approxPi(100000)
3.141583104326456
```

As I said, not very efficient. On the other hand, there is clearly no subtle circularity. Many other series are known to either converge to `pi` or to converge to a value from which `pi` can be easily computed, and many of these other series converge much more rapidly.

**On edit**: @Simon 's suggestion of using the [Gauss-Legendre algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm), together with the module [decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), leads to the following code (which returns the result as a string):

```
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal as d

def approxPi(n):
    eps = 1/d(10**n)
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 3*n #probably overkill, but need room for products
    a = d(1)
    b = 1/d(2).sqrt()
    t = 1/d(4)
    p = d(1)
    dif = a-b
    if dif < 0: dif = -dif
    i = 1
    while dif >= eps:
        a1 = (a+b)/2
        b1 = a*b
        b1 = b1.sqrt()
        t1 = t - p*(a - a1)**2
        p1 = 2*p
        a,b,t,p = a1,b1,t1,p1
        dif = a1-b1
        if dif < 0: dif = -dif
    pi = (a + b)**2/(4*t)
    return str(pi)[:n+2]
```

For example,

```
>>> approxPi(1000)
'3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164201989'
```

With agrees with [this](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/1000_places.html).

The above took less than a second. It took several seconds for 10,000. It would be interesting to see how long it would take to get 1,000,000 digits in Python with this.

Comment: Actually, it's supposed to converge to 10000 digits in ~13 iterations. "The algorithm has second-order convergent nature, which essentially means that the number of correct digits doubles with each step of the algorithm."

Comment: 1000000 digits should be 20 iterations.

Comment: @Simon Yes -- but individual iterations get slow when you are dealing with precision that high. Taking the square root of a 2,000,000+ digit `decimal` object (just 1 part of the iteration) is likely somewhat time-consuming. I don't know enough about the `decimal` class to estimate how long, but if the move from 1,000 to 10,000 was an order of magnitude increase in time, 1,000,000 might be a stretch, at least on my 3 year old laptop. I'll run it and see what happens.

Comment: You are correct, and your code is correct, and the iterations do match. I glanced at the timings and presumed that those operations, would be much faster. Sorry!

Comment: @Simon I was walking my dog when it finished so I don't know exactly, but it took somewhere between 30 and 45 minutes to run (I just started it and walked away with no timing code). The last 10 digits were `5779458151`, which can be verified with various online tools.

Comment: Yes indeed, tested for 10^6 before with 5 extra precision, which worked as expected in 350s.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for your problem:

```
from math import radians, sin


def computePi(n):
    p = n * (sin(radians((360/(2*n)))))
    print(p)
computePi(1000)
```

The theory behind this code is explained in this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588141/how-is-the-value-of-pi-pi-actually-calculated

Comment: R Thank you very much for your time!